# Does anyone know why "Update UML model" doesn't populate Class Repository in Visual Paradigm 16.1 from the VS 2019 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-paradigm

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 and yet again, a new version of VS has broken the third-party tool integration.  I tried to update my class repository (so I can place classes onto my class diagram) and nothing shows up in the class repository.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Paradigm just deployed a patch build (20191260bq) which fixed the code engineering issue on Visual Studio 2019 integration. You can update your VP software to latest patch build to get the problem fixed. Details about update to latest patch can be found at

https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/articles/update-to-latest-patch.jsp
* Please make sure you have pressed the "Update to latest patch" button on the left hand side of the dialog right after launching the update program